# URL scheme for Facebook app wall Post from web page

Tags: android, ios, facebook, url, facebook-android-sdk

I want to post my video link on my facebbok wall, when I view video in iPhone /Android.
For this I have used URL schemes for facebook `(fb://post)`.

But for wall post this is not working if any one any idea, how can I do that please share.

I want same for linkedIn and google plus also, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have use this. This code will open safari from your app. 
If you logged in facebook then you will see the desired text and have to press post button to post.
If you aren't logged in then it will promote you to login after logging you see the desired text.

```
NSString *shareUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@", urlString];
shareUrlString = [shareUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:shareUrlString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

If want to post in facebook without leaving your app then you have to use facebook sdk or social framework in iOS which is supported in iOS6 or higher.

Comment: I think, you're getting me wrong, I want to redirect from my web page to facebook app on my iPhone, not safari from app. I have implemented to redirect from web page to facebook, but don't know how to open post to wall dialog box, if you know about this, please help.